# Is it possible to create a method which returns "new KeyValuePair<T, T>(key, value)"

Tags: c#, generics, methods, keyvaluepair

I want a method which returns a new **KeyValuePair< T, T>**

Why? Because I want to use a method like

```
...
    GetAsKVP("A", "B"),
    GetAsKVP("C", "D"),
...
```

instead of

```
...
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A", "B"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("C", "D")
...
```

when I add values to **params KeyValuePair[] pKVP**

It's faster and more readable.

I tried

```
public static KeyValuePair<T, T> GetAsKVP(T key, T value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(key, value);
}
```

and got an error like;

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: out of curiosity, what APIs are you using that take a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>[]` instead of a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`? with the latter you could pass a `new Dictionary<int,string> {{1,"one"}, {2,"two"}};` for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `T` to the method declaration:

```
public static KeyValuePair<T, T> GetAsKVP<T>(T key, T value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(key, value);
}
```

Or if you want different types for key and value, use this:

```
public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> GetAsKVP<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
}
```

You can use it as you described:

```
var kvp1 = GetAsKVP("foo", "bar");
var kvp2 = GetAsKVP(123, 456);
var kvp3 = GetAsKVP("CurrentDateTime", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> GetAsKVP<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
}
```

A generic method must define the type parameters, they aren't implied by returning or accepting a generic type.

It doesn't make sense to have two type parameters with the same name in your method declaration. If the key and value are always the same type, which wouldn't be very generic, you could do,

```
public static KeyValuePair<T, T> GetAsKVP<T>(T key, T value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare **T** in the Method header (after the name)

```
public static KeyValuePair<T,T> GetAsKVP<T>(T key, T value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(key, value);
}
```

If the compiler can't determine the datatype automatically, you might want to add it to the function call:

```
GetAsKVP<string>("A", "B")
```